# missing commit in git/gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

We can see a commit in remote `master`, but not in local `master`.
git pull/fetch says local branch is up-to-date.

`git show commit-id` in local shows the difference
but `git log | grep commit-id` shows nothing.
Surprisingly `git log commit-id` shows the commit!

(This commit can be seen from SourceTree in remote origin and thus I can copy the SHA1)

When this commit was pushed, it mysteriously bypassed gerrit code review.
gerrit version is 2.8

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your local branch is tracking the remote branch from the correct remote with `git branch -vv`.
Also see where the commit really is present locally with `git branch -a --contains <commit-ish>`.

I'd say if `pull` is stating you are up-to-date, either you track the wrong branch, or the commit is part of your history and you just missed it.

Comment: `git branch --vv` shows `* master                       dcd42ad [origin/master] Merge branch 'release/v1.3.0'`. missing commit is on top of this commit as seen from SourceTree. `git branch -a --contains 1e022e23ee8f430de1f49655ea065dd68420c67e` shows.
  `remotes/origin/refs/for/master`

Comment: `git checkout origin/refs/for/master` shows
`Note: checking out 'origin/refs/for/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state... MESSAGE_REMOVED
HEAD is now at 1e022e2... Test` Looks like a new branch is created by gerrit instead of merging the commit to origin/master and we can see the commit.

Comment: Well, it seems to me you pushed it to gerrit for review but it was not reviewed yet, thus it is not yet in `origin/master`.

Comment: Strangely, it does not show up in "Open" section of gerrit reviews.

Comment: Because you pushed wrongly. You pushed to `refs/heads/refs/for/master` otherwise your command output makes no sense. You should have pushed to `refs/for/master` instead.

Comment: I can swear that I used `git push origin master:refs/for/master` command and had two witnesses watching my terminal :-) It had happened to other co-worker as well, and I was trying to reproduce the issue. Anyway, is there any way to fix this? Because apparently all the subsequent push operations to master fail.

Comment: I have no practical experience with Gerrit. I guess just pushing again with the correct refspec should make the review appear in Gerrit and after review it should appear on `origin/master`